# Post Format Default Content

Tags: content, post-formats, customization

Is it possible to have the default content change as the user selects different post formats? What I want is for backend users of my Wordpress to select different formats, thereby changing between preset content.

Ex. The standard post looks like this by default (using switch( $post->post_type)):

```
[one_fourth]
<h2>About</h2>
<strong>Type:</strong> RPG
<strong>Cost:</strong> Free/Paid
<strong>Platforms:</strong> Web
[/one_fourth]
[three_fourth last=last]
<h2>Description</h2>
[/three_fourth]
```

But if they click on, say, 'Aside,' I want the content to switch to this (i.e. different fields):

```
[one_fourth]
<h2>About</h2>
<strong>Author:</strong> Roger Caillois
<strong>Publisher:</strong> NYU Press
<strong>Pages:</strong> 220
[/one_fourth]
[three_fourth last=last]
<h2>Description</h2>
[/three_fourth]
```

I think what I need is a listener setup to the different radio buttons in the editor that then change the content but beyond that I'm at a loss. Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The magic is in the callback, the handler, for those shortcodes. Where is that code?

Comment: I just plugged that into the functions.php using the "How to Create Custom Post Types in WordPress" (linked below) but that's for post types and not formats. I'm not sure where to locate the code to do something similar when users change the format though.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-default-content-in-your-wordpress-post-editor/

Comment: Again, the magic is in the shortcodes. Those don't show up in the tutorial you mentioned. What told you to use `[one_fourth]`

Comment: Oh, sorry, they are included in the theme I'm using to create columns. (I should probably have left them out of the example as they have no bearing on what I'm trying to do).